# Batch file to copy text files from Sub directories then merge them together

Tags: batch-file, copy, batch-rename

I am looking at trying to do a mass merge of txt files from different directories.

So i have

C:/data/Folder 1/Test.txt
c:/data/Folder 2/Test.txt
c:/data/folder2/testfolder/test.txt

Now my problem is being able to move them all into one directory while renaming them, as unfortunately they all have the same name and then merge them together.

From what i can work out so far,

I can use the following to move them all to one directory

```
For /r c:/data %F in (*.txt) do copy %f C:/exporteddata
```

which will take all the text files from the data directory and put them into the exporteddata directory but this only works if each file name is unique which in my case they are all the same name

I know once i have all the .txt file in the same directory i can use the

```
copy *.txt output.txt
```

running this from within the exported data directory

But what i cant work out is how to put in a rename which will give all the txt files a unique ID before copying them.

Any help would be great.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually copy all files to one without moving to a new location.
You can choose to copy and concatenate all files by removin echo before desired command. I set to copy all files to new directory "AllFilesFolder". Please place the script in the base dir.
Also - to avoid name colision (file with same name copied to AllFilesFolder), an id is added to filenames whe copiing. id is incremented for each file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set id=0
if not exist AllFilesFolder mkdir AllFilesFolder

for /f %%a in ('dir /B /S /A-D *.txt') do (
    echo copy "%%a" "AllFilesFolder\%%~dpna_!id!%%~xa"
    echo type "%%a" >> allFiles.txt
    set /a id+=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This cmd prompt line will merge your files.

```
For /r "c:\data" %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> C:\exporteddata
```

Double `%` to `%%` for use in a batch file.

Comment: @mybrave Your suggested edit was correct, thanks - next time just add the edited character and explain the change in the line provided for that in the edit process.